# Firebase - How to access the deployed application

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-web, firebase-hosting

I have just deployed my flutter app to the Firebase. When I go to the Hosting section on the firebase, I do see domains listed as .web.app and firebaseapp.com. However, when i open any of the links, instead of showing my application It takes me to this page which says -

```
Welcome Firebase Hosting Setup Complete 
You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. 
Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!

OPEN HOSTING DOCUMENTATION
```

How can i access my app and not this message which pops up everytime?

Comment: It sounds like it didn't deploy or didn't deploy your app. Make sure [public](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) points to the directory with the index.html you want to deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so it looks like when you run Firebase init command, It kinds of rewrites your index.html and hence that page. All I had to do was this :

- Run firebase init.
- Define directory to build/web
- Run flutter build web (and not at the start of this procedure)
- Run firebase deploy.